# Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am a new ROS user. I was going through the Publisher and Subscriber tutorials and I attempted to try out the same with an Integer data type. So I made two nodes.

My publisher node :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 //Initialization
 ros::init(argc, argv, "pub_node");
 ros::NodeHandle p;
 ros::Publisher my_var = p.advertise<std_msgs::Int16>("my_topic", 1000);
 ros::Rate loop_rate(1);
 int count = 0;

 //loop
 while (ros::ok())
 {
 std_msgs::Int16 dog;
 dog.data = count;
 my_var.publish(dog);
 ros::spinOnce();
 loop_rate.sleep();
 ++count;
 }
return 0;
}
```

My subscriber node :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Int16.h"

void sub_call(const std_msgs::Int16::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
ros::init(argc, argv, "my_sub");
ros::NodeHandle n;
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("my_topic", 1000, sub_call);
ros::spin();
return 0;
}
```

I am able to build these both. I can run the publisher node and I can see the data being published through

> $ rostopic echo /my_topic

The problem is that as soon as I run the subscriber node, it shows

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

and the subscriber node is stopped.

What does this mean?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243127/segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)/) by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2016-09-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think your issue is in the ROS_INFO call inside of your callback. You are trying to print a string value with `%s`, but your data is an integer value. Try changing the `%s` to a `%d`.

This mistake likely throws a compiler warning when you compile your code. Something like

> format %s expects argument of type char*, but argument 8 has type int

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [R.Mehra](https://answers.ros.org/users/26660/r.mehra/) on 2016-09-06**:
That was it. I understood the problem and the solution now.
Is there any way by which we can check for errors while writing the nodes before running them? AFAIK, building the package doesn't help with error detection, right?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-09-08**:
If you read the output of the compilation when building the package you will be notified of compiler warnings and errors. This is how you check before running. It takes practice to understand what the errors mean and how to fix them, but it is definitely one way to catch errors before running.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-09-08**:
There are also many syntax checkers that can be integrated with an editor or an IDE. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#C.2C_C.2B.2B
http://www.flycheck.org/
https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-09-08**:
Just to add a small note: do consider using GDB to debug if you see segmentation fault. Take a look at this: http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB